# Differences between /clr and /clr:netcore + net6.0

Tags: c#, c++, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, managed-c++

I have a managed C++ project in Visual Studio 2022 (v143) where I've used the following in the settings (Configuration Properties > Advanced):

```
**Attempt #1:**
Common Language Runtime Support: .NET Core RUntime Support (/clr:netcore)
.NET Core Target Framework: net6.0

**Attempt #2:**
Common Language Runtime Support: Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)
.NET Core Target Framework:
```

Each of these attempts worked when used by a C#-.NET 6.0 project. Is there a difference between these two configurations? Is one preferrable to the other? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr#clr-versions

Comment: @IceCode In summary from the link you shared, they are the same. You should answer the question. In either case the answer didn't matter overall- our team went with (what I am assuming is) NetCore. Managed C++ always has me asking why.